# How to Get the Users with No Role from IdentityUser List in Asp.net Core Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identity, razor-pages

I created and seeded two roles(Admin, Manager) and added options to remove users from roles and add them by designing a table of users. But I want the list of users where users are not added to any roles.

I tried with the logical negation operator(`!`) in the `GetUsersInRoleAsync` method, Its saying can't be applied to list of `identityuser` type. Is there any method to get the list of only users(Members) where no roles are added?

Comment: yes please. i need the working example. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> What you want to ask the database is, which users are not assigned to any roles?

You can start by injecting RoleManager class into your controller as it exposes a property called `roles` which we want to use. We also need a UserManager so we're adding that as well.

```cs
// When you're not using the default IdentityRole and IdentityUser class.. 
// you have to change the all of the types IdentityRole and IdentityUser to match those configured in startup.cs.

private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

public RoleAdminController(RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, 
                           UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager) 
{
    _roleManager = roleManager;
    _userManager = userManager;
}
```

Now using `_roleManager` you can say `_roleManager.Roles` and it returns an enumeration of the roles that have been defined in your application.

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<IdentityRole>> GetRoles() {
    return await _roleManager.Roles;
}
```

We want to use that enumeration of roles to build a list of users assigned to any role:

```cs
public async Task<List<string>> UsersInAnyRole() 
{
    var roles = await GetRoles();
    var usersInAnyRole = new List<string>();

    foreach (var role in roles)
    {
        var usersInRole = await GetUsersAssociatedToRole(role.RoleId);
        if (usersInRole.Count > 0)
        {
            usersInAnyRole.AddRange(usersInRole);
        }
    }

    return usersInAnyRole;
}

public async Task<List<string>> GetUsersAssociatedToRole(string roleId)
{
    var names = new List<string>();
    var role = await _roleManager.FindByIdAsync(roleId);

    if (role != null) 
    {
        foreach (var user in _userManager.Users) 
        {
            if (user != null && await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, role.Name)) 
            {
                names.Add(user.UserName); // Or add user.Id if that works better for your use-case.
            }
        }
    }

    return names;
}
```

So right now, after calling the UsersInAnyRole() method it will query the database for all the roles. And then use the user manager to return a list of users associated with that particular role.

Because we're doing this for every role in the application we now end up with a List that contains *all* of our Users that have *any* roles associated to them. The only thing remaining is to compare them to a list that contains *all* of our users' usernames and compare to the list of users that are in roles, to end up with a List that has all the usernames that were not found in our `usersInAnyRole` list.

So we can create two more methods, one for retrieving all the usernames and another for filtering out users that have roles.

```cs
public async Task<List<string>> GetAllUserNames()
{
    return await _userManager.Users.Select(user => user.UserName).ToList();
}

// Let's tie it all together.
public async Task<List<string>> UsersWithoutRoles()
{
    var usersInRoles = await UsersInAnyRole();

    var allUserNames = await GetAllUserNames();

    var usersNotInRole = allUserNames.Where(user => !usersInRoles.Any(userInRole => userInRole == user)

    return usersNotInRole;
}
```

And there you go. Now, if you slightly modify this code to fit your project, you should have a way of finding all the users who are not in any role.

Answer (score 1):

Relationship of users and roles are saved to table `AspNetUserRoles` , so you can perform a query to get the users without any role :

```
var usersWithoutAnyRole = _dbcontext.Users
        .Where(c => !_dbcontext.UserRoles
        .Select(b => b.UserId).Distinct()
        .Contains(c.Id)).ToList();
```

Inject the dbcontext where you want to use :

```
private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbcontext;


public IndexModel(ApplicationDbContext dbcontext)
{
    _dbcontext = dbcontext;
}
```

Comment: its saying DbContext.UserRoles(IList<IdentityUser>) is a method which is not valid in the given context.

Comment: @MizuHaque , you need to inject application dbcontext . see updated reply

Comment: i did that too at first time. the red line is under the UserRoles method.

Comment: Please confirm  your ApplicationDbContext inherits from IdentityDbContext

Comment: yes i did. RazorApp.Data.ApplicationDbContext _context